# Add key with array to json by path

Tags: java, json

I have following JSON structure

```
[
  {
    "key": "val",
    "type": "myType",
    "someSubJson": {
      "key": "val"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "val",
    "type": "myType"
  }
]
```

I need to add new key "myName" with value of ["1", "2"] to some node. For example result json will be like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "val",
    "type": "myType",
    "someSubJson": {
      "key": "val"
    },
    "myName": ["1", "2"]
  },
  {
    "key": "val",
    "type": "myType"
  }
]
```

I have tried com.jayway.jsonpath but it didn't work when my value is array. Maybe some another way to do it or am I missing something?

Thanks

PS

Here some sample code I'm trying to run

```
private String insertValue(String rawJson, String xpath) {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(new int[]{1,2});
    rawJson = JsonPath.parse(rawJson).put(xpath, "myName", arr).jsonString();
    return rawJson;
}
```

In myName key I exptect to got my array but getting "myName": {}

Comment: share your code that is not working

Comment: @sidgate see updated post

Answer (score 1):

It's very late response but may help someone :) One way to do this is as following :

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // JSON provided as input
        String rawJson = "[{\"key\":\"val\",\"type\":\"myType\",\"someSubJson\":{\"key\":\"val\"}},{\"key\":\"val\",\"type\":\"myType\"}]";

        // xpath for adding into first element of JSON array
        String xpath = "$.[0].myName";

        Test test = new Test();

        System.out.println(test.insertValue(rawJson, xpath));

    }

    private String insertValue(String rawJson, String xpath) {

        // Configuration ensuring addition of new leaves without raising exception
        Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL).addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);  
        DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(rawJson);

        documentContext.set(JsonPath.compile(xpath), new JSONArray(new int[]{1,2}));

        return documentContext.jsonString();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "val",
    "type": "myType",
    "someSubJson": {
      "key": "val"
    },
    "myName": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "val",
    "type": "myType"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest to use Jackson instead of JayWay. Jackson has got lot of options to play with Jayson JSON objects.

Comment: Jackson is ment to be working with POJOs that represents json. This it not my case. I need to work with raw json using xpath to modify it

Comment: I think you got it wrong. You can play with the plain JSON as well. There is something called 'merge', that is what for you need to look.